# Paypal Express Checkout for PayPal Buttons

Tags: paypal

I have created some paypal buttons using paypal button manager (My Saved Button Page). All works good so far.

I however want the paypal payment page to open the credit card tab by default. (the tab that says 'Don't have paypal account?').

From other stackoverflow answers I can see I need to use express checkout, and in the API call I need to set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing.

But how do I set this on my normal Paypal payment buttons (the ones I created using Button manager)?

My account on paypal is a business account, and does support Paypal payment pro and Express checkout.

Comment: you need to have special permissions to get eXpress checkout, it comes by default

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that paypal will default to the "don't have a paypal account" for customers who don't have accounts.

PayPal automatically checks if your customers cookies to see if they have ever logged into paypal. If so, it will default to log in, if not then the pay with debit or credit card.

This is why you always see log in. Try clearing your cache and cookies on your browsers and then go to your payments page, you will see.